# how to properly saving loaded h5 model to pb with TF2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, protocol-buffers, tensorflow2.0, keras-2

I load a saved h5 model and want to save the model as pb. 
The model is saved during training with the `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` callback function.

TF version: 2.0.0a
 **edit**: same issue also with 2.0.0-beta1

My steps to save a pb:

1. I first set `K.set_learning_phase(0)`
2. then I load the model with `tf.keras.models.load_model`
3. Then, I define the `freeze_session()` function.
4. (optional I compile the model)
5. Then using the `freeze_session()` function with `tf.keras.backend.get_session`

**The error** I get, with and without compiling:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v2.keras.backend'
>   has no attribute 'get_session'

**My Question:**

1. Does TF2 not have the `get_session` anymore? 
   (I know that `tf.contrib.saved_model.save_keras_model` does not exist anymore and I also tried `tf.saved_model.save` which not really worked)
2. Or does `get_session` only work when I actually train the model and just loading the h5 does not work
   **Edit**: Also with a freshly trained session, no get_session is available.

   - If so, how would I go about to convert the h5 without training to pb? Is there a good tutorial?

Thank you for your help

---

**update**:

Since the official release of TF2.x graph/session concept has changed.  The `savedmodel` api should be used. 
You can use the `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` with TF2.x and it will result in a pb file. However, I am not sure what kind of pb file type it is, as saved model composition changed from TF1 to TF2. I will keep digging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do save the model to `pb` from `h5` model:

```py
import logging
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow import keras

# necessary !!!
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

h5_path = '/path/to/model.h5'
model = keras.models.load_model(h5_path)
model.summary()
# save pb
with K.get_session() as sess:
    output_names = [out.op.name for out in model.outputs]
    input_graph_def = sess.graph.as_graph_def()
    for node in input_graph_def.node:
        node.device = ""
    graph = graph_util.remove_training_nodes(input_graph_def)
    graph_frozen = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, graph, output_names)
    tf.io.write_graph(graph_frozen, '/path/to/pb/model.pb', as_text=False)
logging.info("save pb successfully！")
```

I use TF2 to convert model like:

1. pass `keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(save_weights_only=True)` to `model.fit` and save `checkpoint` while training;
2. After training, `self.model.load_weights(self.checkpoint_path)` load `checkpoint`;
3. `self.model.save(h5_path, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=False)` save as `h5`;
4. convert `h5` to `pb` just like above;

Comment: Hi, write_graph has the path and name separated. it should be 'tf.io.write_graph(graph_frozen, '/path/to/pb, model.pb', as_text=False)'

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering the same thing, as I'm trying to use get_session() and set_session() to free up GPU memory. These functions seem to be missing and [aren't in the TF2.0 Keras documentation](http://faroit.com/keras-docs/2.0.0/backend/). I imagine it has something to do with Tensorflow's switch to eager execution, as direct session access is no longer required.

Comment: Hi James, I think so too. I wonder if they bring some of it back in different libraries or establish new ways.

Comment: from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import get_session

Answer (score 1):

use

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import get_session
```

in keras 2 & tensorflow 2.2

then call

```
import logging
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import get_session

# necessary !!!
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

h5_path = '/path/to/model.h5'
model = keras.models.load_model(h5_path)
model.summary()
# save pb
with get_session() as sess:
    output_names = [out.op.name for out in model.outputs]
    input_graph_def = sess.graph.as_graph_def()
    for node in input_graph_def.node:
        node.device = ""
    graph = graph_util.remove_training_nodes(input_graph_def)
    graph_frozen = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, graph, output_names)
    tf.io.write_graph(graph_frozen, '/path/to/pb/model.pb', as_text=False)
logging.info("save pb successfully！")
```